# How to determine the distance travelled before a maximum acceleration is reached given a constant jerk?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, calculus, jerk

### Problem

Given:

- An initial velocity and acceleration of 0.
- A maximum acceleration $A$
- A constant [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) $J$

How might one determine the distance $D$ traversed before the maximum acceleration $A$ is reached?

### Attempt

I know that, given a *maximum velocity* and *constant acceleration*, I can find the distance with:

$D = \frac{V^2}{2A}$

Similarly, given a maximum acceleration and a constant jerk, I believe I can find the *velocity* at which the maximum acceleration would be reached with:

$V = \frac{A^2}{2J}$

However I'm still unsure how to rearrange this knowledge to solve for *distance* given a maximum acceleration and constant jerk.

### Application Context

I'm currently attempting to improve a linear motion profile for some linear actuators that are present in an art installation that I'm working on in a small team.

Previously, the linear actuator was driven using a constant acceleration selected by us. We could achieve fast movement nicely with high acceleration, and we could achieve slow movement nicely with slow acceleration, however slow movement with a high acceleration resulted in a lot of "chatter" from the motor. The idea is to use a constant jerk rather than a constant acceleration to achieve smoother behaviour at both low and high speeds.

I have been working on an implementation that seems to be almost complete, however I'm struggling to determine the distance at which I should begin decreasing deceleration in order to arrive at the target position with a velocity and acceleration of 0. It occurs to me that this is the same as solving the distance required to reach the maximum acceleration, hence the framing of this question.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

*For the most part, this is a cross-post from the math exchange where I had [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4006111/) before realising the question is likely better suited here.*

Comment: Integrate J 3 times. Since all except J start at 0, $a=Jt$, $v=\frac{1}{2}Jt^2$, $d=\frac{1}{6}Jt^3$. You have maximum for a, find t then find d.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the tip! My thoughts are then as follows: If I know that $a = Jt$, then I know that the time until maximum acceleration is reached is $t = \frac{A}{J}$. Knowing this, I can solve for distance using $d = \frac{1}{6}Jt^3$, replacing $t$ with my result. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Sounds about right to me.